# angular prevent form validation until touched

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, touch-event

On an Angular 8 project,

I have a create and edit component.

I just duplicated/refactored create to make the edit.

on arrival in edit-mode the component subscribes to a behavior subject which has been next'd the object to be edited (since it's a behavior subject, regardless of timeframe, my component correctly instanciates the object)

in the edit case instead of instantiating the form with empty values I instanciate  it with the recuperated values straight up.

good.

now to the user it effectively looks like he is editing that object.

The issue is Form validation conditions were of course previously met for the object to be created in the first place so the Submit button is highlighted and ready to go.

I expected the touched property to already be a validation condition and for the submit button to be disabled until values are touched.

(different would be ideal but touched is a good starting point)

right now my edit form starts out as valid and I don't want that.

I don't want to "hack" this by setting one of the field's invalid flag because I don't pre-emptively know what the user will want to edit and I want it to be any field and for the user to only have to edit 1-n field for the form to be valid.

Comment: Which Angular version do you use?

Comment: angular 8, i should have said so sorry

Comment: Some users down-vote a question when it does not have code or you don't want to show what you tried so far. But the question make sense and you very well explained what you tried already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Angular ^8:

Mark the form as pristine after setting the values to the controls:

```
this.form.markAsPristine();
```

And add the condition to submit button for making it disable if the form is untouched:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="form.pristine">Save</button>
```

Comment: nevermind with `form['pristine']` it works perfectly, thanks! I don't even need the `markAsPristine()` since my form was just instanciated with those values.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Control i.e. any type extending AbstractControl such as FormGroup, FormControl, ArrayControl…

They will be marked as dirty by default (unless of course you made your own implementation).

Therefore, when you create such a Control and assign them validators, those validators will be triggered at once.

For instance, assuming `ErrorOnValidate` is a validator which will always return an error, the following `formGroup` will immediately hold the errors returned by the validator.

```js
const formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup(
      {
        key: new FormControl('value'),
      },
      {
        validators: [ErrorOnValidate],
      }
    );
console.log(formGroup.valid); /// false
```

How to prevent this behaviour ?

You need to create the form first, then set it as pristine and then only attach validators to that one.

```js
const formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup(
      {
        key: new FormControl('value'),
      }
    );

formGroup.markAsPristine();

formGroup.setValidators([ErrorOnValidate]);

console.log(formGroup.valid); /// true
```

In this way, the formGroup will run the validator (and therefore in this example hold the validator's error) when a controller is touched.

**But…**
Now you do have a FormGroup with values and validators which will not do anything until it is touched. However, as soon as you will bind this FormGroup with a input, the input will touch the control and therefore trigger the validations, meaning all this effort is lost.

An alternative is to create a FormControl without any validators and to add those to the form only only once the view did init.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.formGroup.setValidators([ErrorOnValidate])
}
```